# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de un atributo en tabla dinámica?

Tags: jquery

Estoy creando una tabla de calificaciones de n filas con m columnas que obtengo de mi DB, e imprimo los valores conforme pinto la tabla. Estos valores los asigno en una celda que con un id específico, ya que lo construyo mediante el id del alumno con el id del trabajo calificado, pero al momento de tratar de obtenerlo, me viene vacío.

creo la tabla de la siguiente forma:

```
$.each(arrayJS_insc, function(key, value){  
    newTable += '<tr><td id="'+value["values"]["alumno"]+'"><font size="2"><strong>'+value["values"]["alumno"]+'</strong></font> </td>'
        for (var i = 1; i <= num_crit-1; i++) {
            newTable += '<td id="0"><center><input id="'+criterios[i]["idCriterio"]+'_'+value["id"]+'" val_ant'+criterios[i]["idCriterio"]+'_'+value["id"]+'="" type="number" step="1" placeholder="S/C*" class="inputcentrado form-control lib" name="nom" max="10" min="0" value=""></center></td>'
        }
    newTable += "</tr>"
});
```

donde num_crit es la cantidad de criterios que voy a calificar.

y de esta forma asigno los valores:

```
var id_comb=0;
$.each(califs, function(key, value){
    id_comb = value["id_criterio"]+"_"+value["id_usuario"];//genero el id de cada caja de texto

    $("#"+id_comb).val(value["calificacion"]);//asigno el valor actual a la caja de texto
    $(this).attr('valor_c',value["calificacion"]);//asigno el valor actual al atributo para comparar si hay cambio de calif
})
```

pero el valor que asigno a `$(this).attr('valor_c',value["calificacion"]);`
no puedo obtenerlo para actualizarlo, lo que intento hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
$( ".lib" ).focusout(function() {
    var valor_c = $(this).attr("valor")
}
```

Todo lo anterior lo hago desde la misma función.

¿Cómo pudiera obtener ese valor para compararlo con el nuevo y no tener que hacer un update incluso cuando el valor es el mismo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu problema. Y me pregunto, ¿por qué no haces eso al momento de crear los valores que tendrá la tabla en el servidor?

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar. Necesito saber qué valor tengo al momento de poner una calificación, para actualizarlo. Lo más fácil aquí es hacer un update en mi base de datos cada que se agrega una calificación, lo que no se quiere es, ir a la base de datos cuando no cambia la calificación.

Comment: Dedica el primer párrafo de tu pregunta a explicar el contexto para poder ayudarte mejor. No logro entender lo que quieres, la explicación es un poco confusa. A veces hay soluciones simples, pero todo se complica porque uno no se detiene a analizar la lógica del programa. Intuyo que esto es más sencillo de lo que parece, pero no entiendo bien el contexto.